# jQuery - Url.Action LOCAL Machine Pathing Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, post

Why would only my local machine require me to have the following:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("ControllerName/ActionName")', { param: valueHere }, function (result) { successFunc(result); }).fail(function (error) { alert(error); });
```

While on other computers it would be the normal:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("ActionName")', { param: valueHere }, function (result) { successFunc(result); }).fail(function (error) { alert(error); });
```

This does not work for my computer in question:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")', { param: valueHere }, function (result) { successFunc(result); }).fail(function (error) { alert(error); });
```

I'm trying to figure out why it's not working only for one of my computers and not all of them.

So, having 4 computers 3 will only run with `ActionName` while only one will only run with `ControllerName/ActionName`. What could be possible problem?

Thanks for your time.

Edit 1: Still having the same problem even with first answer. Please see comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")
```

The issue is probably caused by a discrepancy in the controller name so it is better to be more specific.

Comment: I just checked and that works on my other 3 computers, but not the one with the problem. The one with the problem will only work if I put "ControllerName/ActionName". On the one that does not work it gives me error: Requesting http:// localhost/SolutionName/ControllerName/ActionName but could not find. Could have been moved or renamed. When using "ControllerName/ActionName" on my other 3 computers I get error: Requesting http:// localhost/SolutionName/ControllerName/ControllerName/ActionName but could not find. Could have been moved or renamed.