# jQuery - Url.Action Controller/Action Issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-post

Why would only my local machine require me to have the following:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("ControllerName/ActionName")', { param: valueHere }, function (result) { successFunc(result); }).fail(function (error) { alert(error); });
```

While on other computers it would be the normal:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("ActionName")', { param: valueHere }, function (result) { successFunc(result); }).fail(function (error) { alert(error); });
```

This does not work for my computer in question:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")', { param: valueHere }, function (result) { successFunc(result); }).fail(function (error) { alert(error); });
```

I'm trying to figure out why it's not working only for one of my computers and not all of them.

So, having 4 computers 3 will only run with `ActionName` while only one will only run with `ControllerName/ActionName`. What could be possible problem?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The first one should never run, as that particular overload accepts an action name, not a couple URL segments. Look at the markup of your page... What is `Url.Action` rendering?

Comment: 1st Code: On Computer 1 it is rendering Controller/Action, on Computer 2, 3 and 4 it is rendering Controller/Controller/Action; 2nd Code: On Computer 1 it is rendering Action (but does not see it so it throws errors), on Computer 2, 3 and 4 it is rendering Controller/Action and working properly; 3rd Code: On Computer 1 it is rendering Controller/Action and throws errors because it says it does not see it. On Computer 2, 3 and 4 it renders Controller/Action and works properly.

Comment: After rendering, your javascript line for example #1 should read: `$.post('/ControllerName/ActionName', {param ... ` What are you getting for example #1?

Comment: Example 1: $.post('/Solution1/Controller/Controller/Action')

Comment: Sorry, hit enter thinking it would move to a new line. Example 2: $.post('/Solution1/Controller/Action'), Example 3: $.post('/Solution1/Controller/Action')

Comment: This is all from the computer with the issues by the way.

Comment: Discard example 1, it is not constructed properly. Both 2 and 3 are correct, but understand that the application path "Solution1" is prefixing your URL. The other computers, are they perhaps servers where you are not setting a virtual directory?

Comment: No, they both are using a virtual directory just like computer 1.

Comment: More information: The virtual directory name is Solution1 so I would think that /Solution1/Controller/Action would work, but for some reason computer 1 will only accept /Solution1/Controller/Controller/Action even though they are all using the same code. That's why I'm curious if it could be some setting I'm not aware of since it will only work as $.post("ActionName") on the server I am using when putting it on network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Url.Action LOCAL Machine Pathing Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780553/jquery-url-action-local-machine-pathing-issue)