# jQuery - Url.Action Path Issue for Local Machine

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

**Question:** I have messed with this issue for a couple days now and still have not found any solution to it. The issue is when I am on my local machine I am trying to use the following code:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("TestAction", "Home")', function () { alert("Success"); }).fail(function () { alert("Error"); });
```

`Home` is the name of my controller - `HomeController`. I specify the controller name since I have more than one controller in my solution.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TestAction()
{
    return View();
}
```

I do this to see if my code will even hit this method at all, which it does not.

This code does work, however, if I start a new project and try it. I need it to work on my current project though and starting it over is not an option since it works for other computers, just not mine and it even works on network.

The above code gives me the path: `TestSolution/Home/TestAction` which is correct, but the code never hits the `TestAction` function so shows the "Error" alert box instead of "Success". It does show "Success" on other computers and on the network, just not my computer.

So, for my computer I have been using the following code (which ONLY works for my computer and no others nor the network, which is to be expected):

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Home/TestAction")', function () { alert("Success"); }).fail(function () { alert("Error"); }
```

This code gives me the path: `TestSolution/Home/Home/TestAction` which is incorrect, but hits the function TestAction and shows alert box of "Success" only for my computer, other computers running this and the network would display "Error" alert box.

Note: I have also tried the following code that just behaves like the first:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("TestAction")', function () { alert("Success"); }).fail(function () { alert("Error"); });
```

Path for this is: `TestSolution/Home/TestAction`

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - Url.Action LOCAL Machine Pathing Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21780553/jquery-url-action-local-machine-pathing-issue)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that it works fine on every other computer except yours that would seem to point to configuration problem on your computer. You state that when the URL that you send to is `TestSolution/Home/Home/TestAction` then it works. Have you checked your IIS configuration for the web site/virtual directory to make sure you don't have an extra `Home` in there?

You may also want to check out Phil Haack's route debugger (http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx) to see if that will give you any additional clues as to what's going on on your local machine.

Comment: Thanks man, I had a Home folder inside of my TestSolution directory. So, it was trying to go to TestSolution/Home (the folder)/Home (the controller)/TestAction instead of TestSolution/Home (the controller)/TestAction.